# HttpUrlConnection chunk size and video files

Tags: java

I am using HttpUrlConnection to upload files with servlet... The problem is I can upload files max 10000*4096 length only :( Even the chunk mode method doesn't help... I looked all around google and found it is a sun's bug or something... So the only thing I can do is come to terms with it ... But I wonder is there some alt java lib which make possible upload really big files?

Plz help me to understand

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are running into some configuration limit in either the upload servlet or with your web container.  Without more details it is hard to be more specific.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick comment.

Comment: This is applet -> servlet thing... So I am trying to use HttpUrlConnection to upload binary file to servlet. Well it works fine but for small files (< 40Mb) only :( If I set the max_chunk_size more than 40Mb I am getting OutOfMemory error so it is the major problem I guess but I don't know what should me do to make my applet upload big files with HttpUrlConnection ?

So I dearly hope you can give advise.

Comment: I looked all around google and this is a very big problem as for inner limits of HttpUrlConnection... So I decided to choose maybe another java lib which can handle the problem? But I don't know where to look for? Please advise me the best way to do.